# Makefile looping over directories

Tags: make

I need to create links for multiple directories in a Makefile.

The links (for all files in `./topdir/`) should go from `./anotherdir/<file>` to `./topdir/<file>`.

I tried:

```
create-links: ./topdir/*/
    @for f in $^; do  \
        echo "this is my path: [$${f}]" && \
        DIR=$(shell basename $${f}) && \
        echo "make link from ./anotherdir/$(DIR)" ;\
    done
```

There are those files in ./topdir

```
dir1
dir2
file1
file2
```

`f` gets assigned correctly with both dirs and their relative path (e.g. `./topdir/dir1`).

I only need the dirname without the path. This is what `basename` should do.

But DIR is always empty. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(shell basename $${f})` is processed by Make before it runs the recipe; it isn’t handled in the loop. You need to run everything using the shell:

```
    @for f in $^; do  \
        echo "this is my path: [$${f}]" && \
        DIR=$$(basename $${f}) && \
        echo "make link from ./anotherdir/$(DIR)" ;\
    done
```

or

```
    @for f in $^; do  \
        echo "this is my path: [$${f}]" && \
        DIR=$${f##*/} && \
        echo "make link from ./anotherdir/$(DIR)" ;\
    done
```